# How to extend custom listView item more than 10 items through String array android?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter, custom-lists

> I want to create custom list more than 10 elements. When I fill an
>   String array more than 10 elements and click the 11th item then app
>   isn't run.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    int position=0;
    String[]items={"ab","cd","ef","gh","jk","lm","no","pr","st","uv","wx"};
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_country);
        ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_list,items);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
                {
                Intent intent;
                position=p3;
                switch(p3){
                    case 0:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hi.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    case 1:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ba.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dc.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Fe.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Hg.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Kj.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ml.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,On.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Rp.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Ts.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, Spinner_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }

    });
}
}
```

> at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4169)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6743)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6717)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6663)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6846)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native
>   Method) 05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:177)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6817)
>   05-18 09:49:57.933 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6869)
>   05-18 09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
>   05-18 09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
>   05-18 09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:707) 05-18
>   09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
>   05-18 09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 05-18
>   09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 05-18
>   09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 05-18 09:49:57.934 14335
>   14335 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 05-18
>   09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 05-18 09:49:57.934
>   14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   05-18 09:49:57.934 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 05-18
>   09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E
>   AndroidRuntime                               Process:
>   com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 14335 05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E
>   AndroidRuntime
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.Spinner_Activity}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 05-18 09:49:57.940
>   14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2123)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1801)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4495)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4453)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4814) 05-18
>   09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4782) 05-18
>   09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.mycompany.myapp.List_Widgets$100000000.onItemClick(List_Widgets.java:75)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1197)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3166)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:4131) 05-18
>   09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3878)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:11776) 05-18
>   09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2959)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2636)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2965)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2965)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2965)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2965)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2650)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:446)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1848)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3315) 05-18
>   09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:408)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:12015) 05-18
>   09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4855)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4638)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4169)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4222)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4188)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4315)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4372)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4169)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4222)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4188)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4196)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4169)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6743)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6717)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6663)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6846)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:186)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native
>   Method) 05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:177)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6817)
>   05-18 09:49:57.940 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6869)
>   05-18 09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
>   05-18 09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
>   05-18 09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:707) 05-18
>   09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
>   05-18 09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 05-18
>   09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 05-18
>   09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 05-18 09:49:57.941 14335
>   14335 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 05-18
>   09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 05-18 09:49:57.941
>   14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   05-18 09:49:57.941 14335 14335 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 05-18
>   12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E
>   AndroidRuntime                               Process:
>   com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 29469 05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E
>   AndroidRuntime
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.Spinner_Activity}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? 05-18 12:10:59.002
>   29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2123)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1801)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4495)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4453)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4814) 05-18
>   12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4782) 05-18
>   12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at
>   com.mycompany.myapp.List_Widgets$100000000.onItemClick(List_Widgets.java:88)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1197)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3166)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4119) 05-18
>   12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 05-18
>   12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 05-18
>   12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 05-18 12:10:59.002 29469
>   29469 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809) 05-18
>   12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 05-18 12:10:59.002
>   29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   05-18 12:10:59.002 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 05-18
>   12:10:59.008 29469 29469 E   AndroidRuntime
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: I have loaded LogCat above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.Spinner_Activity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

According to your logcat, I think you have forgotten to add **Spinner_Activity** to **Manifest file**. Check if Spinner_Activity is present there. If not, just add it there.

```
<activity android:name=".Spinner_Activity"></activity>
```

I suggest you to create new activities via menu **File -> New -> Activity -> Empty Activity** and studio creates both activity, layout and note in manifest by itself.

As for me, you code works well

Comment: Thanks, I read it from LogCat and check out Manifest.xml. But I didn't notice that once again wrote the line </activity>.Thanks again.